# Asynchronously loading web page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to  synchronously load the contents of an external webpage onto my site. I'm using the following code for that:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            var xhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("siteloader").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", href, true);
            xhttp.send();
</script>
</head>
```

However, this only works when `href` is a link to a page that is on the same server as the current page. For example if `href` was `https://www.facebook.com` nothing would happen but if it was `log.txt` it would load its content as I have a file which is named that.

How can display external web content on my page?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the same-origin policy, for security reasons, `XMLHttpRequest` only allows request to URLs from the same domain as the page on which the script has been run.

For more information see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script on your server that fetches the content from the third party website and then outputs it. 
You call this script with your ajax request and you should be fine.

btw. : as you are already using jQuery in your code, it might be more consistent and easier to use the ajax function of jQuery for getting the content.

Comment: I'm very new to query and ajax. Can you recommend a tutorial or a website where I can learn how to write such scripts to fetch data from third party websites.